# Azure site recovery provider : Setup could not proceed as no compatible product is found

Tags: azure, hyper-v

I am trying to protect my hyper v virtual machine by using azure site recovery vault, I am using below link :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/site-recovery-hyper-v-site-to-azure/

Step 3 : When I try to install provider I found below error :

[image]

My Virtual machine and local PC full fill prerequisite for site repository provided in above link..

Advance thanks...

Answer (score 2):

In provided link : Got to know that I am running the Hyper-V on Windows 8 machine. Till date Windows 8 is not supported OS for configuring ASR.

Question : What versions of Windows Server hosts and clusters are supported using above link?
Answer : Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2 can be used when using ASR and Hyper-V replication between a Hyper-V sites and Azure.

Please find below link for reference:
[site recovery overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/site-recovery-overview/)

[Site recovery Faq](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/site-recovery-faq/)